# Dynamic data showed grid image. how to drag n drop sort grid in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

How to drag N drop sorting index image grid moved using css framework tailwind css in react js?
drag n drop sort index image grid moved to work. dropped index image shows dropped index item and another index image sorting.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77426639/edit) your question to include your source code as a working [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be tested by others to provide an answer faster. [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.